# Two classes one with reference to function to another different this value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have problem and I don't know how to solve it:

```
        this.bWords.push(word);
                    ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

here is my code:

```
function multiWords(words) {
    class AWords {
        constructor(words = []) {
            this.words = words;
            this.addWordFn = () => {};
        }

        setAddWordFn(fn) {
            this.addWordFn = fn;
        }

        passWords() {
            this.words.forEach(word => this.addWordFn(word));
        }
    }

    class BWords {
        constructor() {
            this.bWords = [];
        }

        addWord(word) {
            this.bWords.push(word);
        }
    }

    let x = new AWords(words);
    let y = new BWords();

    x.setAddWordFn(y.addWord);
    x.passWords();

    return y.bWords;
}


console.log(multiWords(["one", "two", "three"]));
```

Do you have any ideas why there is different `this` value?
Many thanks
Pati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem occurs here:

```
this.words.forEach(word => this.addWordFn(word));
```

because the function you've set for `addWordFn` here:

```
x.setAddWordFn(y.addWord);
```

Needs a different value of `this` than you are calling it with.  You can fix it by binding the right value of this to your callback:

```
x.setAddWordFn(y.addWord.bind(y));
```

Remember that for regular functions, the value of `this` inside the function is determined by how the function is called.  When you call a function with `obj.method()`, the `this` value inside of `method()` will be set to `obj`.  So, you're calling `addWord` with the wrong `this` value because you've made it a method of some other object (that does not also have the data it needs) and are calling it off that object.